# Check whether worksheet is protected when no password has been specified

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have not been able to find any way to check whether an Excel Worksheet is in protected mode when a password hasn't been specified. I'm working with Office 2013 using the Excel Interop Assemblies.

If there is a password, you can check the HasPassword property, but when there is no password it does not appear that there is any method to determine whether the worksheet is currently protected.

I would also accept an event-based approach if there's any way to determine when the user selects to "Unprotect" the worksheet. The trouble right now is that when they do that, I don't know it's unprotected, and I can't respond appropriately.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by trying to unprotect the sheet without a password and catching the error after checking the `ProtectContents` property.

Comment: But if you call Unprotect() on a protected workbook with no password, it becomes unprotected, there is no error. So I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: You do exactly as I said.  Check if it is protected using `ProtectContents`.  If it is protected you then try the unprotect.  If there is an error you know there is a password.  If there is no error simply reprotect without a password.

Comment: I'm sorry that there isn't an easier way to do it, but `excel-interop` is strange sometimes.